# No puedo agregar datos a una tabla en HTML usando un ciclo For

Tags: javascript, html, html5

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML=`<br><br>
            <table class="table table-dark" id="Table">
    </table>`;

    $("#Table").append('<tr><td align="center" style="color:#FFBD09">Palabras Clave</td>'+
    '<td align="center">Sentimientos</td>' + 
    '<td align="center">Conceptos</td>');

            for(var i=0; i<respuestaURL.keywords.length; i++){
              $("#Table").append('<tr>' + 
              '<td align="center" style="dislay: none;">' + respuestaURL.keywords[i].text + '</td>'    );
            }
            for(let a=0; a<respuestaURL.concepts.length; a++){
              $("#Table").append('<tr>' + 
              '<td align="center" style="dislay: none;">' + respuestaURL.concepts[a].text + '</td>'    
              );
            }
```

El problema es que no puedo meter los datos del `respuestaURL.concepts[a].text` a la columna `sentimientos` si no que se enciman con las respuestas del `respuestaURL.keywords[i].text` que se ponen en la columna de `palabras clave`. Como puedo hacer para que `respuestaURL.keywords[i].text` se ponga en la columna de `sentimientos`?

Muchas gracias

Comment: No entiendo bien que estas haciendo; eso lo estas escribiendo directamente en tu HTML?

Comment: Listo, ya lo edite. Lo estoy haciendo desde Javascript

Comment: No estás cerrando las etiquetas `tr`. Prueba a cerrarlas, aquí: `$("#Table").append('<tr><td align="center" style="color:#FFBD09">Palabras Clave</td>'+
    '<td align="center">Sentimientos</td>' + 
    '<td align="center">Conceptos</td></tr>');` y aquí: `$("#Table").append('<tr>' + 
              '<td align="center" style="dislay: none;">' + respuestaURL.concepts[a].text + '</td></tr>'` Y, en lugar de usar `append` todo el rato dentro de los bucles, es mejor que construyas toda tu cadena y hagas un solo `append`. Cada vez que haces `append` el DOM es obligado a actualizarse.